# VBA code for to show random sheets from excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 15 sheets on an excel file with name Sheet 1 to Sheet 16, I have a button on Sheet 1 when I pressed it will show 10 sheets (Sheet 2 to Sheet 16)

I do some research but couldn't find the best solutions.

Regards.

Comment: It is not possible to show 10 sheets at a time. So put your codes here and clear your desired result.

Comment: Can you provide example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for the help I already figure it out. I run a random number and place it in cell and use the number to call the Name of sheet to become visible

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    ActiveWindow.Close

    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    With ActiveWindow
        .Top = 7
        .Left = 205
    End With

    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical

End Sub
```

It will show 10 times the active sheet, vertically. Then you only have to find a way to show the needed one per active window.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will randomly select one of the sheets "Sheet2" to Sheet16" when triggered by `CommandButton1` on your Sheet1 tab.

```
Sub Commandbutton1_Click()

    Dim RandomNumber As Integer

    Randomize
    RandomNumber = Int((16 - 2 + 1) * Rnd + 2)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & RandomNumber).Select
End Sub
```